# SCSI termination with external device (removing internal one)

Tags: cable

I have SCSI adapter Adaptec ASC-29320ALP U320 (rev 10):

http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/installation_guides/29320alp_ig.pdf

For years I have been using with **internal** LTO-2 tape drive with a properly terminated cable. Recently this device got damaged and I bought a new LTO-3 **external** tape drive which comes with a terminator attached to it and an LVD cable.

The plan is to remove the old internal LTO-2 device from the computer box and to use only the new external LTO-3 drive. As far as I understand from the manual to use an external device I need to connect it with the LVD cable and terminate it (as it is the one and only, i.e. last one). This part is clear.

However I am not an expert on SCSI and I am looking for answers to the following question:

1. Should I keep the internal cable connected to the addapter although no device is connected to it just because it is terminated? Or can I completely remove it?
2. If I remove the internal cable, should the internal port which is on the very PCB be terminated somehow? Or can it simply stay without any cable?

In short - can I completely get rid of the internal cable or will that cause some problem (data loss or other) because the internal port will not be connected to anything?

I hope someone can clarify this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to connect any internal peripherals and your Adaptec HBA can provide termination (all Adaptec cards I have seen in the past 20 years could do that), then you may disconnect the internal cable. To check the termination provided by your Adaptec card, you should enter the card's BIOS menu at boot, and look for the termination setting. It is most probably in 'Automatic' mode, which is the preferred setting. Either that or 'Enabled' should provide termination. If it is 'Disabled' then you should change it. If you cannot find the termination setting there at all, that may be a problem.

Comment: Thank you. I see it is set on Automatic. I also received a reply from Adaptec tech support and they confirmed I can get rid of the internal cable.